# Stability of a dipole magnet undergoing eddy current braking in a cylindrical tube

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, stability

Consider a cylindrical dipole magnet with strength $B$ undergoing eddy current braking in a conductive cylindrical tube with the axis of the magnet aligned with the axis of the tube.

The magnet feels a retarding force $F_{eddy} =\mathcal{V}vB^2σ$

The arrangement is in equilibrium (by symmetry) in all directions apart from along the axis. But is it a *stable* equilibrium in the off-axis directions?

That is, if you knock the magnet sideways by a small amount, is there a restoring force? If you turn the magnet slightly off the axis, is there a restoring couple?

Bonus question: could it be ***made*** stable by mechanically attaching some other magnets to the moving magnet?  (the goal is to make it stable without significantly reducing the braking force)

Comment: Apparently, we need to create a numerical model. I see no other way how to answer these questions.